# Extracting a string from fdisk command

Tags: shell-script, fdisk

I want to write a shell script, which will run `fdisk -l` and extract a string `/dev/sdbn` from the output of `fdisk -l`.

Using extracted word I want to mount it to `/mnt`.

For Example:

```
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot    Start    End    Blocks    Id    System
/dev/sdb1    *         1    493    3956672    6     FAT16
```

How do I only extract the string `/dev/sdb1`?

Comment: How do you determine what device you are trying to filter on? Do you want everything that is /dev/sdbX`? It's not clear what you are actually asking for...

Comment: Are you sure that this is really what you need? With the device plugged in, you can find out what partition it has by looking inside `/dev`, e.g. if you know it's `sdb` you can list `/dev/sdb[1-9]*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
fdisk -l | grep -o '^/dev/sdb[0-9]'
```

The `-o` option causes `grep` to print only matching pattern.

**Updated**

If you want all except `/dev/sdaX`, you can use:

```
fdisk -l | grep -o '^/dev/sd[b-z][0-9]'
```

Comment: Thank You so much...this is what I exactly wanted. @Gnouc

Comment: suppose when I have another device mounted simultaneously, at that time this will not work as you described.                                                For example, when I mount two device at a time, then how do I extract both string i.e `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdc1` ?

Comment: `awk` and `sed` commands are much faster than the `grep`

Comment: @Thushi: really? Can you give some evidences?

Comment: @Thushi that is not true. While you might be able to find specific cases where `sed` or `awk` are faster than the equivalent `grep`, it is not a general rule. In most cases, `grep` will be faster than either `sed` or `awk`. Even in this very simple case, the `awk` approach took 0.02968 seconds while the `grep` took 0.02782. This is the average over 100 runs. Please don't make unsubstantiated claims like that.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command : 
`fdisk -l | awk '/\/dev\/sdb[0-9]/ {print $1}'`

Comment: That's just an example to get the first word from the line.He can filter out the lines using his logic.

Comment: @jasonwryan: how about this???

Comment: That's much better! You could throw in an anchor, `^`, for good measure... Upvoted.

Comment: suppose when I have another device mounted simultaneously, at that time this will not work as you described. For example, when I mount two device at a time, then how do I extract both string i.e `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdc1` ?

Comment: @arzyfex:Then the command will be: `fdisk -l | awk '/\/dev\/sd[a-z][0-9]/ {print $1}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`...

Since a directory-path contains `/`, I've chosen to use `_` to delimit the sed-command (although one usually use `/`, *any* symbol can be used as delimiter).

`fdisk -l | sed -n 's_^\(/dev/[^ ]*\) .*$_\1_p'`

Comment: that works but it gave me all partition like,                                                        /dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
/dev/sda4
/dev/sda5
/dev/sda6
/dev/sda7
/dev/sda8
/dev/sdb1
rather than this, I just want /dev/sdb1, any help on this ?

Comment: Oh, my bad...  I misunderstood.  You could use `head -n 1` after the `sed` - or simply `fgrep 'sdb1'` or `fgrep '/dev/sdb1'` before or after the `sed`... You can also simply change the script and replace `/dev/[^ ]*` with `/dev/sdb1` and keep the rest as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
for getting `/dev/sdb1`

```
fdisk -l | grep -w "/dev/sdb1" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: I guess `grep` is not required.`awk` only can match the pattern and print the first word `fdisk -l | awk '/\/dev\/sdb1/ {print $1}'`

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't have root access, you can use a simple `ls`:

```
ls /dev/sd* | grep -o '/dev/sd[a-z][1-9]'
```

Edit regular expression as you want.

**UPDATE:** As @StéphaneChazelas mentioned, presence of device files won't confirm existence of the underlying device. It would be safer to query `/proc/partitions` instead:

```
awk '$NF ~ /^sd[a-z][0-9]+/ {print "/dev/" $NF}' < /proc/partitions
```

Comment: Or just `echo /dev/sd[a-z][1-9]`, though depending on your system those devices files may exist even though the underlying device doesn't exist. Also `awk '$NF ~ /^sd[a-z][0-9]+/ {print "/dev/" $NF}' < /proc/partitions` to query what the kernel really knows about partitions on devices using the sd subsystem.